# Firebase console reads cost

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Does using the firebase console and clicking on different collection/documents count against my read operations quota?

I have about 2 real users and about 13 fake ones and my usage is showing 1100 reads so far today. There are only about 30 documents in the entire database!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Any document read from the server is going to be billed.  It doesn't matter where the read came from.  The console should be included in that.

Comment: OMG! that sucks

Comment: this is the most annoying part of trying to debug things

Comment: What are the solutions that we can use to avoid this??