# Why Firebase Firestore count reads operations while I am just adding new documents only?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have created and an API endpoint with Firebase Functions usign node.js. This 
API endpoint collect JSON data from client browser and I am saving that JSON data to Firebase Firestore databse using Firebase Functions.

While this works fine but when I see Firestore usage tab it's shows really high number of read operations even I have not created any read function till now.

My API is in Production and and current usage data is : Reads 9.7K, Writes 1K, Deletes 0.

I have already tried to check with Firebase Firestore Document and Pricing but never seems to find anything on this issue.

I am using Firestore add function to create document with an auto generated document id. ValidateSubscriberData() is a simple function to validate client req.body inputs which is JSON data.

```
app.post('/subscribe', (req, res) => {
    let subscriber = {};
    ValidateSubscriberData(req.body)
        .then(data => {
            subscriber = data;
            //console.log(data);
            subscriber.time = Date.now();
            return subscriber;
        })
        .then(subscriber => {
            //console.log(subscriber);
            // noinspection JSCheckFunctionSignatures
            return db.collection(subscriber.host).add(subscriber);
        })
        .then(document => {
            console.log(document.id);
            res.json({id: document.id, iid: subscriber.iid});
            return 0;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log({SelfError: error});
            res.json(error);
        });
});
```

I don't know this is an issue with Firestore or I am doing something in a way that makes read operations internally but I want find a way so I can optimize my code.

English is not my first language and I am trying my best explain my issue.

Comment: Can you attach the api endpoint code & what it does.

Comment: @AkhilSurapuram I have updated my code.

Comment: is it the only endpoint with Firestore ?

Comment: @AkhilSurapuram Actually this is my bad I am not thinking about reads which I made through Firebase console so I have figured it out. Anyway thanks for helping  me sir :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think Firestore is working perfectly fine and my code too. I assume Firebase is counting those reads which I made through Firebase Console.

To verify this I have clicked on Data tab on Firestore page and scroll down to make all document name/id visible. And after that I see 1K Reads added on my old stats. So its proven Firestore counting all reads even its from firebase console and it is obvious but my bad I have not thinking about this before.

I don't think this question has any relevance but may be people like me find it helpful before posting any silly question on this helpful platform.

Comment: Reads made by the Firestore console indeed count the same as reads made by your app through the API. This is a common source of confusion for developers new to Cloud Firestore, so good work on figuring it out on your own. :) 
Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/51073484, https://stackoverflow.com/q/53000130, https://stackoverflow.com/q/56434008